# unable to convert object data type to int using python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a file named sample.csv. It looks like below:

no   sample_id

30   7f6fe071848736985d3eaf751e498407416c3udhfy3hfbshj
23   897gfe071848736985d3eaf751e498407416c3udhfy3hfbshj
21   34frfe071848736985d3eaf751e498407416c3udhfy3hfbshj
100  1090e071848736985d3eaf751e498407416c3udhfy3hfbshj

If I try to change the `sample_id` column which contains 64 digit alpha numeric characters from object to int data type it is returning `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10` error.

I tried the below steps to convert, but nothing worked  - all returned a value error:

````
df['sample_id'].astype(str).astype(int)
df['sample_id'] = pd.to_numeric(df['sample_id'])

df['sample_id'] = df.sample_id.astype(int)

the reason why i want to convert the alpha numeric object type to int data type is to apply hashing on the sample_id column using the below function.

import hashlib
def encrypt_id_sha256(sample_id):
    hashed_sample_id = hashlib.sha256(bytes(int(sample_id))).hexdigest()
``` return hashed_sample_id

df["sample_id"] = df["sample_id"].apply(encrypt_id_sha256)


changed the function to below to directly hash from hex..it worked for me..Thanks All..

hash = sha256(bytes.fromhex(sample_id)).hexdigest()
````

Comment: do **not** post images or links to images of you data. Provide it as *text* in the question itself

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? The data has alphabetic characters. I suggest doing `astype(str)` and call it a day.

Comment: In any case, are those supposed to be hexadecimal digits?

Comment: Now that you have edited, there are digits which are not hexadecimal. In that case, how do you expect to convert a random string to an int... What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the numbers are hexadecimal (base-16) in which case turning them into an int normally will not work. Instead do this:

```py
df["sample_id"].apply(int, base=16)
```

Comment: Thank you.. i tried your solution it converts the alpha numeric to int values but if i try to apply hashing function it returned OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer